# Python ctypes ERROR: exception: access violation writing 0x00DEF6CC

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

I'm trying to import a **C/C ++** dll with lib **ctypes** and use a **function** that it has internally, when passing the parameters to this function I always encounter the error:

```
ERROR: exception: access violation writing 0x00DEF6CC

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've used `cast`,`string_buffer` and `POINTER`, but still I still get the same error

Here is the code:

```py
import ctypes
import sys

file_path = './lib/poc-pagamento-dpos.dll'
integracao_pos = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(file_path)


def main():
    try:
        integracao_pos.carregarRegistros()
        integracao_pos.atribuirCallbacks(callback=display_msg)
        transacao_credito()
    except OSError as e:
        print("ERROR: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(1)


def transacao_credito():
    pNumeroControle = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"1234567")
    pValorTransacao = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"15000")
    pNumeroCupom = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"1234567")
    pTipoOperacao = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"FA")
    pNumeroParcelas = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"2")
    pValorParcela = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"0")
    integracao_pos.transacaoCartaoCreditoDPOS.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,
                                                          ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
    integracao_pos.transacaoCartaoCreditoDPOS(pValorTransacao, pNumeroCupom, pNumeroControle,
                                              pTipoOperacao, pNumeroParcelas, pValorParcela)



def display_msg(msg):
    print("----------------->{}".format(msg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**C++ implementation**

```
    char cNumeroControle[6 + 1];
    char cTipoOperacao[2 + 1];
    char cNumeroParcelas[2 + 1];
    char cValorParcela[12 + 1];
    char cValorEntrada[12 + 1];
    char cValorTaxaServico[12 + 1];
    char pPermiteAlteracao[1 + 1];
```

```
 extern POCPAGAMENTODPOS_API int transacaoCartaoCreditoDPOS(char* pValorTransacao, char* pNumeroCupom, char * pNumeroControle,
        char* pTipoOperacao, char* pNumeroParcelas, char* pValorParcela);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: in your C program would you by chance overrun some buffer you passed? the string buffers look really small, and it seems that you're writing in one/several of them. can you show the code of the C function?

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisFabre first of all, thanks to reply, I edited the question with the implementation, and the size of the buffers it's ok